# Difference between Laravel Session:token and csrf_token

Tags: php, laravel, token

Is there a real difference between `csrf_token()`

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
```

and `Session::token()` ?

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}" />
```

They both seem to produce the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel provides a variety of different methods for performing the same tasks.

The first example is a helper function: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers

The second example is the Session facade: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/facades

There is no difference in the result as they will both call the same method in the end.  The actual method they are calling is: https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Session/Store.html#method_token